# KafkaUtils class in kafka 0.11

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, spark-streaming-kafka

we are using spark streaming to read and write from kafka and uses the  KafkaUtils libary in spark-streaming_2.11 which has the kafka 0.10.0 libs. Right I am in the process of upgrading the kafka-client jars to 0.11 to use some feature but since spark-streaming has the kafka 0.10 its not getting used.I  tried to exclude the same from spark-streaming but its complaining about below KafkaUtils class which is in 0.10 only. 
 Even 2.3 is coming bundled with kafka0.10 (spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.cloudera2.jar) . How i can i get rid of this dependency of KAfkautils in 2.10 ?

**SCALA  CODE for spark streaming Direct Stream creation**

```
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
    val directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
                            ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topicSet, 
                            conf.kafkaParams))
```

**POM.XML**

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0.0</version>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.cloudera1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>            
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is the spark kafka dependency that you are using for migrating to kafka broker 0.11. Also, as per the official doc, you should not be importing org.apache.kafka dependencies yourself. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

Comment: try removing kafka-clients from the pom, this is not necessary.

Comment: Not: DirectStream is deprecated as of Spark 2.4. Use `spark-sql-kafka`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing "kafka-clients" as this is not necessary.

Also if you are using apache spark , make sure to use the below one.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks  i added this but  this also has Kafka 0.10  . My intent is to use kafka 0.11 as it has the feature which we need to use.

Comment: @AjithKannan The Spark documentation explicitly says not to add kafka-clients yourself. The latest `kafka-sql-0.10` uses `2.x` clients anyway. 0.10 just means 0.10 **and higher**